# Notepad++ Find/Replace Regex Help

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am having issues doing a string replacement in Notepad++, and need some help.

My file:

```
LastName,(tab)FirstName[optional]MiddleName
```

Some times there is data that has a middle name, sometimes not.

```
Public,JohnQ.
Doe,John
Clinton,WilliamJefferson
```

would be:

```
Public(tab)John(tab)Q
Doe(tab)John
Clinton(tab)William(tab)Jefferson
```

I want to split it out into this:

```
LastName(tab)FirstName(tab)MiddleName
```

Comment: Is [optional] actually the word optional in square brackets or does it mean something else?

Comment: No, it means sometimes there is a Middlename (that starts with a capital letter)

Comment: Does it have to be in one regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for adding the sample input. It helps immensely to have that around. Try this and see if it does what you want.

Find, making sure **Match case** is checked:

```
([A-Z][a-z]*),([A-Z][a-z]*)(.*)
```

Replace with:

```
\1(tab)\2(tab)\3
```

Of course, `(tab)` is actually a tab character that you have to place in the replacement string yourself.

Answer (score 0):

An ugly regex like this works for me on the example you've provided:

```
(\w+),(\w+?)(([A-Z]\w*\.?)?)\n
```

replace with

```
\1\t\2\t\3\n
```

Note:

- This only works if the middle name starts with a letter in the A-Z. You might be able to replace `[A-Z]` with `[[:upper:]]` if notepad++ supports it (I don't know).
- I need that second bracket around the middle name part because I need to match at least an empty string when there is no middle name.

Comment: I checked and found Notepad++ 5.9 added support for non-greedy assertions, but upgraded and I still can't get it to work. What find settings did you choose?

Comment: It doesn't? I didn't really try it directly in Notepad++, just in Rx Toolkit. Well, if it doesn't, your regex is the way to go!

Comment: Yeah, Notepad++ has a horrible regex implementation. At least you made me upgrade (its auto-updater is just as bad and never told me about 5.9).

Comment: Tip: My php-IDE of choice: [Komodo](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide) (not free though).

Comment: I use Aptana across all platforms, Notepad++ for just quick editing of any source file since it supports tons of languages.